# no single point of failure with traditional RDBMS

Tags: nosql

I am working in a trading applications that depends on an Oracle DB.

The DB is crashed two times and the business owner wants some solution in which the application still works even the DB is crashed.

My team leader introduced Cassandra NOSQL as a solution as it has no single point of failure but this option will make us move from the traditional relational model into the NOSQL model which I consider as a drawback.

My question here, Is there a way to avoid a single point of DB failure with traditional relational DBMS like Mysql, postgreSQL,......etc ?

Comment: If you set up Cassandra badly, without any fundamental DBA knowledge, and proper environment, as you did with Oracle, it will be a failure again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NoSQL isn't the only possible solution.  You can set up replication with MySQL:

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication-solutions.html
```

and

```
 http://mysql-mmm.org/
```

and concerming failover discussions:

```
http://serverfault.com/questions/274094/automated-failover-strategy-for-master-slave-mysql-replication-why-would-this
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you just need a cluster of Oracle database instances, rather than just a single instance, such as [Oracle RAC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/products/clustering/overview/index.html).

If your solution for the Oracle server being offline is to use Cassandra, what happens if the Cassandra cluster goes down? And are you really in the situation where it makes sense to rewrite and re-architect your entire application to use a different type of data store, just to avoid downtime from Oracle? I would suspect this only makes sense for applications with huge usage and load numbers, where any downtime is going to cost serious money (and not just cause embarrassment to the business folks to their bosses).

Comment: Our application will be re-architectured and developed from scratch anyway and in the same time it is a brokerages application so any down time will cost serious money. if this is the case is it best to go for nosql or try to obtain the main problem solution with traditional RDBMS ? I do know know

Comment: that is a completely subjective question that can only be answered by the team of people working on the application :)

Comment: Oracle RAC, proper hardware, proper storage, proper AC and proper power. 

Proper in this context means no SPOF.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to avoid a single point of DB failure with traditional relational DBMS

No, that's not possible. Simply because when one node dies. It is gone.

Any fault-tolerant system will use several nodes that replicate each other. You can still use traditional RDBMS, but you will need to configure mirroring in order for the system to tolerate a node failure.